# Increased amount of vandalism

Tags: support

In the last few days we've been seeing an increased amount of vandalism edits, mostly including spam advertisement. I'm not sure if this is only a perceived or an actual problem, but I thought I raise the problem here. Maybe the SE officials are interesting in taking a look at this.

Also, maybe somebody has better statistics at hand then "it feels like a lot".

List of (recent) offenders:

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14882 (1)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14954
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15034
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15066
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15175 (1)

(number): same post

Comment: I see it as free fodder for review badges. We have quite enough high rep users to go through the review queues that the volume shouldn't be an issue IMHO.

Comment: I read on another SE site that there was a brief spate of vandalism going around network-wide (seemed to be a few users across all sites), and that we just had to stay the course

Comment: FYI - we've seen this over on [Christianity SE](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/how-to-deal-with-spam-attacks-on-this-site) as well.

Comment: @Wikis: I don't know this vandal seems a bit more subtle, by inconspicuously hiding nonsense in edits.

Comment: Ah, so a different person then, probably. I thought it might be linked since it was reported around the same time - both sites had a spike in vandalism.

Comment: @Wikis - that was where I had seen it mentioned too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been popping up from time to time. We looked into it with the Community team the last time we had a slew of them, but in the end the outcome was that we just have to reject them as they come. For now, I've locked the post that was being targeted.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't knew (or remembered) there were previous instances of this.

Comment: Be sure to flag any posts that repeatedly get vandalized.  Mods can lock them down to prevent further vandalism.

Comment: Also, a user having a post flagged as spam is a severe black-mark and they lose the privilege of asking/answering for a while, if they're not outright deleted. If it truly is spam, flag as such, not as 'low quality' or other reasons

Comment: @Robotnik If the problem is that these are *suggested edits*, which can't be flagged. And they're being submitted anonymously, so they can't be suspended.